# Powershell Converting Body to HTML Body

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script that looks to folder for updates and sends out an email if there has been any updates.  How do I change or convert the body of the email to a URL or HTML link instead of text?

The below path and servers are examples.

Here's my script:

```
    Param (
    [string]$Path = "\\Desktop\Myfolder\status updates",
    [string]$SMTPServer = "smtp.myfolder.com",
    [string]$From = "Admin@me.com",
    [string]$To = "Admin@me.com",
    [string]$CC = "Admin@me.com",
    [string]$Subject = "New Status Report"
    )

$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = $To
    Cc = $cc
    From = $From
    Subject = "$Subject"
    Smtpserver = $SMTPServer    
}

$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10) }
If ($File)
{   $SMTPBody = "`The following files have recently been added/changed.  Please copy and paste the following link to Windows Explorer:`n`n"
    $File | ForEach { $SMTPBody += "$($_.FullName)`n" }

    Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
```

Comment: What are you expecting the URL in the email to go to when clicked? Open the file in browser? You wouldn't be able to really link to a local file that opens explorer from most email systems, it would be in browser only. Depending on the file type, that may be acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell offers a `Convert-ToHTML` cmdlet which is perfect for your needs.

Simply pipe your content, `$SMTPBody`, into it.  You can even apply a CSS file to make the e-mail look just that extra bit better.

```
$HTMLBody = ConvertTo-HTML -body $SMTPBody -CSSUri http://www.csszengarden.com/examples/style.css
```

Then reference `$HTMLBody` in your e-mail.

The sky is the limit with CSS. If you'd like to read more, [I covered this topic in a blog post](https://foxdeploy.com/2014/05/23/using-html-formatting-to-create-useful-webpage-reports-from-powershell/).  Here's an example of what we can create.
[image]

In this example, we use the `-Pre` and `-Post` parameters to add content above and below the table.  The table is created by piping objects into `Convert-ToHTML` with the `-As Table` property.  This cmdlet with just four parameters can create Web page worthy output!

Comment: Not all clients will automatically interpret HTML; some will read the HTML as raw text. To ensure that the appropriate MIME section headers are included to "force" the interpretation as HTML, in addition to your process here, you need to add the `-BodyAsHMTL` switch to the `Send-MailMessage` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `$SMTPBody` value to be a string containing the HTML, and then add the `-BodyAsHTML` switch to your `Send-MailMessage` command.

```
...
$SMTPBody = "<em>This is italicised</em>"
...

Send-MailMessage -Body $SMTPBody -BodyAsHTML -To ...
```